# Convert String into Time

Tags: java, string, time

I have an array of Strings like this:

```
private String time[] = {"8:00:00 AM", "8:00:00 PM"};
```

The array of strings is then displayed in a `JComboBox`.

My question is: How can I convert/cast/parse the selected String into a Time object whilst still keeping AM and PM times distinct? Would it be best to simply use 24 hour times?

Thanks in advance for any help/advice/guidance.

Comment: (DateFormat + Date) or JodaTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is sample code: You need to iterate through your array and populate yourString value.

```
SimpleDateFromat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
Date dt2 = dt.parse(yourString);
```

Here is a link for [Simple date formater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: how come same 'dt' variable name with different java object class assignment?

Answer (score 2):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` class methods.

```
String timeStr="8:00:00 AM"; 
SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
Date dt=df.parse(timeStr);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
for(String str : time) {
    dates.add(sdf.parse(str));
}
```

Comment: I wrote the exact same answer (letter by letter) but updated the page before submitting and found this, +1 for thinking "EXACTLY" the same.